# Overdispersed Poisson Distribribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm interested in finding the probability distribution of the following process:

Let $X \sim Poisson(\lambda_1)$, and $Y \sim Poisson(\lambda_2)$.
If $X$ is observed, the system 'waits' for time $t_x$ before being able to observe $X$ or $Y$ again. That is, time continues to advance, but during the waiting time $t_x$, neither $X$ nor $Y$ can be observed. Similarly for $Y$ with time $t_y$.

What is the probability of observing $X$ in the following t seconds, starting in an un-waiting state?
What is the probability that the next observation is $X$, and what is the expected time to observe it?

I'm finding this problem difficult to solve from an analytical perspective. I've already simulated it but I'd like to solve it analytically.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I really don't know where to start with incorporating the waiting times :(

Comment: I don’t think the problem is described clearly enough.  What exactly is meant by “observing” a stochastic process?  For what duration of time are the processes observed?  What is the rule about choosing between observing process $X$ or process $Y$ next?  Do we choose probabilistically? Or,  can we observe both processes at the same time over some interval of time?  How do the individual arrivals from the $X$ and $Y$ processes affect our decisions about what to observe, and for how long we make the observations?

Comment: Say the result of the observation (a realization of $X$) is $5$. What is the relationship between $5$ and $t_x$?

Comment: Observing a poisson process X here means a single count observation. So in the same way that you can find the expected time for the first poisson event to occur, that first event will trigger the wait time, and then once that wait time is over, the system is reset

The Poisson observations themselves are instantaneous, but observing them triggers the wait time.

Comment: So in infinitessimal time bins, you have counts of 0,0,0,0,0,0,0...,1...wait for time $t_x$ ... 0,0,0,0,1....wait for time $t_x$.... etc.

Comment: I think you mean that you have two classes of Poisson processes, and you observe individual arrivals from these processes.  Depending on the type that arrives next, you "timeout" for a certain time (and we ignore all arrivals, of both types, that occur during the timeout). After each timeout, we go back to "observing mode" which is really just waiting for the next arrival to occur (which could be from either type).  Is this correct?

Comment: That's right! Thanks

Comment: Still no progress on my end btw. This is a hard problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the system may work like this:  We have two independent Poisson arrival processes $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$, with rates $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, respectively (in units of arrivals/sec).  The timeline is segmented into *renewal frames* $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ that work like this:

- We start each renewal frame $i$ in *observation mode*, which lasts until the next arrival.
- If the next arrival is type 1, we go to sleep for time $T_1$ seconds. On the other hand, if the next arrival is type $2$, we go to sleep for time $T_2$ seconds. Here, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are fixed nonnegative constants.
- We ignore all arrivals that occur while we are asleep.
- The next renewal frame $i+1$ occurs when we wake up from sleep.

---

The basic theory is that if $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ are independent Poisson processes of rates $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, then the combined process is also a Poisson process, has rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$, and each new arrival of the combined process is independently type 1 with prob $\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ (independent of the history of interarrival times and types before this new arrival).

So if we start a new renewal frame $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, the time $Y_i$ to the next arrival is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, so it has average time $1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$.  Regardless of the value of $Y_i$, the new arrival is type 1 with prob $\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$, and it is  type 2 with prob $\lambda_2/(\lambda_1+ \lambda_2)$.

Renewal theory allows us to compute the steady state fraction of time we are in the observation mode, the sleep-type-1 mode, and the sleep-type-2 mode: Let $H(t)$ be the total time we are in the observation mode during $[0,t]$, and let $S_1(t), S_2(t)$ be the total time we are in the sleep-type-1 mode and sleep-type-2 mode, respectively, during $[0,t]$.  Then:

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{H(t)}{t} &= \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+ \frac{\lambda_1T_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} + \frac{\lambda_2T_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}} \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} \\
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_1(t)}{t} &= \frac{\frac{\lambda_1T_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+ \frac{\lambda_1T_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} + \frac{\lambda_2T_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}} \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} \\
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_2(t)}{t} &= \frac{\frac{\lambda_2T_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+ \frac{\lambda_1T_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} + \frac{\lambda_2T_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}} \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} 
\end{align}
Notice that these fractions of time sum to 1.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! It looks like renewal theory deals only with the limit as time goes to infinity. Do you know what the distribution looks like for $t < \infty$ ? If not, do you perhaps know how quickly the convergence takes place?

Comment: Finite time analysis is usually much harder.  In this case, we can get upper and lower bounds on, say, the expected time spent in the observation phase during $[0,t]$. The Wald equality may help. I think those bounds, when divided by $t$, converge to the limiting fraction of time (given above) with error $O(1/t)$.  You can also compute the probability that there are at least $k$ renewal frames during $[0,t]$, and there may be an interesting recursive calculation for the probability that we go into sleep-type-1 mode at least once during $[0,t]$.  What is the context? What is this analysis for?